# converting array into json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a callback where i am getting the below `console output` when printing `row`.

```
output of row [ 'Name', 'Language' ]
output of row [ 'English', 'Fr' ]
output of row [ 'German', 'Gr' ]
output of row [ 'France', 'London' ]
```

I want to convert the above array into a valid json **excluding** the first **row** alone like this.

```
{
  "English" : "Fr",
  "German" : "Gr",
  "France" : "London"
}

  .on('record', function(row, index){      
      console.log("output of row", row);
      var obj = {};
        row.forEach(function(column, index) {
          obj[row[index].trim()] = row[index].trim();
        })
        record.push(obj);
      }
    })
```

**Additional Code**

I am getting csv data which i am pushing it into a **row each time**. Below is the CSV Data and the array i am getting each time i read the csv data...

```
Language,Name
Fr,English
Gr,German
London,France

output of row [ 'Name', 'Language' ]
output of row [ 'English', 'Fr' ]
output of row [ 'German', 'Gr' ]
output of row [ 'France', 'London' ]

  cvcsv()
    .from.string(csv)
    .transform( function(row){
      row.unshift(row.pop());
      return row;
    })
    .on('record', function(row, index){
      console.log("output of row",row)
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what is the code which is generating the rows? Also, are you getting an array of rows, or consecutive calls of the callback generate new rows each time?

Comment: Use stringify var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I am getting array on consecutive calls of the callback which is generating rows each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're getting array on consecutive calls of the `callback()` which is generating rows each time, you can collect the rows you need, parsing each one of them into a `"key": "value"` pair, adding it to an object. Then, you can use the `JSON.stringify()` method to turn your object into a valid JSON string.

Here's a working solution according to the code you provided:

```
var rows = {};

cvcsv().from.string(csv).transform(function(row){
    row.unshift(row.pop());
    return row;
}).on('record', function(row, index){    
    if (index > 0) rows[row[0]] = row[1];
});

jsonRows = JSON.stringify(rows);

// Log to the console to check
console.log(jsonRows);
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{"English" : "Fr", "German" : "Gr", "France" : "London"}
```

Comment: I am not really getting the row = callback() thing, if possible can u get me a fiddle... it would be really great.

Comment: @Shane how are you getting these rows exactly then? Provide us more code, edit your answer. I'm creating a working snippet.

Comment: @Shane I updated my question, see if it fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Can you use JSON.stringify(yourArray)?

You can remove the first element from the array using shift:
yourArray.shift();

Comment: Actually, the OP hasn't got an array of rows

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified method to help translate an array of array(size 2)

```
function addToObject(object, row, keyIndex, valueIndex) {
    object[row[keyIndex]] = row[valueIndex];
}

function test() {
    var data = [[ 'Name', 'Language' ],
                [ 'English', 'Fr' ],
                [ 'German', 'Gr' ],
                [ 'France', 'London' ]];
    var obj = {};

    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
        // NOTE data[i] can come from any place
        addToObject(obj, data[i], 0, 1);

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: The OP hasn't got an array of arrays

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, it doesn't really matter if an array exists or not they can modify the code to fit there needs. The test method is a "test".